# Returning a static with allocWithZone

Tags: objective-c

Working off an idea from the Big Nerd Ranch guide to iOS programming, I'm trying to define singleton object in the following manner:

```
@implementation ImageStore

static ImageStore *defaultImageStore = nil;

- (id)init
{
    if (defaultImageStore) {
        return defaultImageStore;
    }

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }

    NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(clearCache) name:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification object:nil];

    return self;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return [self defaultImageStore];
}

+ (ImageStore *)defaultImageStore
{
    if (!defaultImageStore) {
        defaultImageStore = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }
    return defaultImageStore;
}
```

This works fine, but the analyzer complains about allocWithZone, saying

> Object with +0 retain counts returned to caller where a +1 (owning) retain count is expected

I think the code is just tricking the analyzer and that what's happening is OK, but is there a better model to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't bother with all that stuff.  This is my pattern:

@implementation MyClass

```
-(id) init { ... } /* normal init */

+(MyClass*) defaultMyClass
{
    static MyClass* theObject = nil;
    @synchronized([MyClass class])  // remove synchronzed block in single threaded app
    {
        if (theObject == nil)
        {
            theObject = [[self alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return theObject;
}
```

Possbily you can hide the initialiser in a class extension so that it is documented that you shouldn't use it.

There's also the GCD method (the below is stolen from Rob Napier's link) which is actually more lightweight.

```
+ (id) defaultMyClass
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static MyClass* theObject = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{ theObject = [[self alloc] init]; });
    return theObject;
}
```

I've always resisted the GCD pattern because to my eye it looks less obvious what is happening.  However, that's nothing that can't be fixed with a comment!  The locks used by GCD are more lightweight in comparison to @synchronized, so this will be faster.

Comment: Given the extra steps involved with my method, yours does seem a lot more straightforward...

Comment: As a general rule, if you're overriding +alloc, you're doing something wrong. I know that Apple posted code explaining how to do it (they weren't actually recommending the pattern; just explaining it). That page has probably sent more developers down the wrong road than any other document in Cocoa. JeremyP's solution is one of many. The best today (and the one that Apple recommends at WWDC) is probably the GCD singleton: http://adamhuda.com/creating-a-singleton-with-gcd

Comment: Apple does seem to at least implicitly recommend the pattern I'm using here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32 The difference being that they call retain in allocWithZone.

Comment: There's also the new fancy way of accessing singleton objects using `dispatch_once()`, if you want to get your hands dirty with GCD :)

Comment: @Rob Napier: Good point about the GCD thing.  I'm going to update my answer to steal that, if you don't mind :)

Comment: @BenFlynn, that is the document I was referring to when I said "That page has probably sent more developers down the wrong road than any other document in Cocoa." Re-read the first paragraph of the section where they explain that the provided code is for a "strict implementation," which you almost never need (even if you did, this is an over-tricky way to do it). The more flexible solutions they discuss in the first paragraph are what you should be using, and is presented in JeremyP's answer.

Comment: @Rob Napier The thing that makes it strict, overriding allocWithZone, isn't super complicated as far as I can see. It just returns the singleton instance if someone tries to alloc an ImageStore. That's not to say you don't provide a perfectly elegant solution, but I just don't see any language in their to dissuade me, and it's the pattern the Big Nerd Ranch Guide uses.

Comment: Yes; it would have been helpful if Apple would be more clear on this page why it's a bad idea (and why they very seldom use it). I've opened a documentation bug for the page. One of the reasons its a bad idea is that it creates confusion if any part of the Singleton is mutable. I +alloc two objects and mutate one of them. Magically my other object mutates. This is a bug waiting to happen. For immutable types, -init... can replace one object with another for performance reasons (such as in NSNumber), but it is not a sensible way to create a singleton. +sharedInstance is the correct way.

Comment: If the shared instance is *necessarily* the only instance, then calling -init should be a programming error (NSAssert()), not quietly fixed in +alloc such that the caller believes he has two objects when he actually has one. For immutable objects (like NSFileManager), it is not actually a problem, but for mutable singletons it is wrong. ImageStore sounds mutable.

Comment: @Rob: Personally, I always try to make sure that alloc/init always give back a sensible object (not the singleton). This makes it easy to manufacture pristine objects for unit testing purposes.

Comment: @RobNapier That is an interesting point because it would make sense to expect an object you alloc to to be unique. My ImageStore is wrapping a mutable array, so I'm not sure if I'd call it itself mutable or not. In Java you can hide the scope of the constructor to force people to call the singleton method (or factory method for factories) but I don't see that's a possibility. Suppose you wanted to enforce strictness with dispatch_once -- what would you do with calls to alloc / init?

Comment: Create a private init method (`initSingleton`). Then in `init` call `NSAssert()` and return `nil`. This will ensure that you do not accidentally try to create a unique instance, turning it into a programming error (assertion). Most of the time, however, there is no need to enforce uniqueness. Look at NSNotificationCenter. You're free to create multiple centers if you like, and there are even reasons to do so (rare, but sometimes). As JeremyP notes, this also makes mocking easier for testing. Don't force uniqueness if it's not really required.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment, solving the compiler warning was as simple as adding a retain to the statement, which is mentioned in an [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32).

```
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return [[self defaultImageStore] retain];
}
```

Side note: I hadn't mentioned this, but I am developing for iOS, and found that the dispatch_once method seem to halt my app's execution.

Comment: dispatch_once() is the correct solution on iOS. If it's halting, then you have a bug.

Comment: I will try that sometime. For now this works (retain is a no-op for defaultImageStore, but it makes the analyzer happy).

Comment: I think I hadn't removed all of the code from the method I was using before when I tried dispatch_once. Works great.